# What is the purpose of MSBUILDENSURESTDOUTFORTASKPROCESSES property of msbuild

Tags: .net-core, msbuild

I was trying to change my building configuration from `dotnet test <solutionname>` to `dotnet msbuild /t:VSTest <solutionname>`, because as I thought, all those build related dotnet command are wrappers for msbuild. I have around 4 test projects, one of them contains ca. 700 tests.

The problem is, that while `dotnet test` command runs all tests, `dotnet msbuild /t:VSTest` runs and arbitrary number of tests each time, usually around 100.

I compared the msbuild output and found that the only difference is `MSBUILDENSURESTDOUTFORTASKPROCESSES = 1` variable; once I set it in the command line it started working for `dotnet msbuild /t:VSTest` as well.

The question is - is it intended to work that way? Is it supposed to be set when using `dotnet msbuild` or `dotnet msbuild` should not be used at all and I should use specific command like `dotnet build` for building and `dotnet test` for testing?

Because I personally find it more consistent using always just msbuild with different targets and would like to change building configuration like this.

I hardly ever understand what it does from the name, therefore would like to avoid writing something like `dotnet msbuild /t:VSTest /p:MSBUILDENSURESTDOUTFORTASKPROCESSES=1` in my build config, it just looks like a hack.

Comment: [The code](https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild/search?q=EnsureStdOutForChildNodesIsPrimaryStdout&unscoped_q=EnsureStdOutForChildNodesIsPrimaryStdout) and this [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/1503) might give you more  information. At a glance, it looks like this property was introduced because of "dotnet test" issues.

Answer (score 0):

From the issue @christian-k linked in his comment: `MSBUILDENSURESTDOUTFORTASKPROCESSES=1` “changes the way MSBuild creates child processes to force them to share a stdout stream with the parent. The `dotnet` cli uses this workaround when you invoke `dotnet test`.” (https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/1503#issuecomment-410732193)

So my understanding would be it is fine and no different for you to use `dotnet  msbuild /t:VSTest /p:MSBUILDENSURESTDOUTFORTASKPROCESSES=1`.